# How to make a water ripple animation from a grid of squares?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, grid

I'm looking for an algorithm to make a ripple effect on a grid of squares so having a grid of squares how can I make it so when the user clicks on a square this produces a wave like animation of the surrounding squares? the following image illustrates the desired effect.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a working example in JavaScript.

http://jsfiddle.net/nsN57/17/

You can of course enhance it further, but your requirements were a bit vague.

Comment: You nailed it! just what I was looking for to get me started, thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

You could represent each grid square as a node in a finite element model and assume the mouse click to be equivalent to an impulse response at the node associated with the grid square that was clicked.  Read up a bit on [Modal Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_analysis), [Normal Mode shapes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_mode), and [Finite Element Analysis Methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_element_method) for some ideas of how to approach this.

Comment: Finite difference would be better - use the fact that it is a regular grid to simplify the maths.